# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation in IIS published website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

I got an error on website published on server and server hangs every time.

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 6/11/2013 10:18:04 AM 
Event time (UTC): 6/11/2013 2:18:04 PM 
Event ID: 63f8257b9ec047db97f0da880dbb8008 
Event sequence: 1480 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/ProjectName-2-130154277455550525 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /ProjectName
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ProjectName\ 
    Machine name: ProjectName-DB1 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 3424 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\Classic .NET AppPool 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: TargetInvocationException 
    Exception message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 

Request information: 
    Request URL: https://www.ProjectName.com:443/ProjectName/Forms/formname.aspx 
    Request path: /ProjectName/Forms/formname.aspx 
    User host address: 123.63.157.2 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: ProjectName-DB1\IISSecUser 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 5 
    Thread account name: ProjectName-DB1\IISSecUser 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.InvokeMethod(ObjectDataSourceMethod method, Boolean disposeInstance, Object& instance)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments)
   at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

can any one help to solve this error.

Comment: It looks like the error is occurring somewhere in the binding of a control.  Some source code would probably be helpful.  See if the suggestions here help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231187/asp-net-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-invalidcast